# OpenShift MongoDB ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift

When attempting to connect to the mongodb-2.4 cartridge i keep getting the following

```
 ==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log <==
  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
      at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:893:11)
      at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:916:20)
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1075:14)
```

I am creating the connection string as below

```
if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD){
  connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" +
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ':' +
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + '/' +
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
}
```

It looks like when it fails it thinks the port is 27017 but when i run rhc port-forward appname it shows me the following different port for mongodb

```
Service Local                OpenShift
------- --------------- ---- ------------------------------------------------------
haproxy 127.0.0.1:8080   =>  127.6.174.2:8080
haproxy 127.0.0.1:8081   =>  127.6.174.3:8080
mongodb 127.0.0.1:42346  =>  5747fa8f70-appname.rhcloud.com:42346
node    127.0.0.1:8082   =>  127.6.174.1:8080
```

Any ideas as to whats going wrong?

Comment: MongoDB is running on 42346 and log is showing that you are going to connect mongodb on Port 27017. Try it connect it on 42346

Comment: @JitendraKhatri i already stated that above. If the mongodb cartridge is provided by OpenShift why is it returning the wrong port number in the variable provided process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT ??

Comment: Try this format of connection string, mongodb://<user_name>:<password>@localhost/<databse_name>. It is working well for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out if you remove a mongodb cartridge after it has been deployed alongside the web servers cartridges and then replace the mongodb cartridge the web server variables don't get updated. I needed to restart the web tier servers in order for them to the get the new mongodb setting variables updated.

Comment: I think I have your same issue. Did you just restart the server? Because it's now working for me

Comment: did you replace the mongo instance? I ended up moving away from openshift because after spending the time to set it up i then went to upgrade my account and noticed they don't accept quite a lot of countries including mine (Australia).

Comment: I found out that it was not related to this. By mistake I was overwriting the process.env variable with webpack, therefore my script was not able to retrieve the correct environment variables. What do you mean by "they don't accept quite a lot of countries"? We are based in Italy and we are currently using the bronze plan

Comment: I am in Australia.. pretty big country but apparently i cannot sign up for the bronze or silver plan as payments are not accepted from here... would have been nice to know before setting up servers etc.

Comment: Yes, this surprise me. What other service are you using to host your application? It's not easy to find cheap and reliable Node hosting services

Comment: Ended up just using the heroku hobby dynos.